# Netty - The best way to send message concurrently in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, netty

I have 150 threads.

Each Thread has **Netty Client** and it is connected to server.

Should I use more 150 threads to send?

Should I use 75 threads to send?

Should I use no thread to send?

My local test is not meaningful. (I can't operate server over 50)

please help me.

Comment: Why do you have 150 threads? Netty only uses `AMOUNT_OF_PROCESSORS * 2` threads to send in its default coniguration. Your high thread counts seems like a design problem

Comment: hmm low Thread causes delay when server receives data.

Comment: I mean ... all data don't come at same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no golden rule for this.  Depending on your application, you can find that;

- just one connection with one thread is enough to use all the resources of the machine.
- Using around the number of CPUs to 2 * the number of CPUs is enough to use all the CPU of the machine.
- If you have synchronous requests (instead of asynchronous ones) and a high network latency you might find that you are spending most of the time waiting for data in which case more connections would help mitigate this latency.

My preference is to allow asynchronous messaging/requests and allow a single connection to use all the CPU/resources on the machine if it makes sense because while you might get better result when you test with 150 busy connections, in the real world you they might not all be active at once or to the same degree.

Comment: Thank you for answer. clients' "connecting" are not active at once but servers' writeAndFlush(sending) is almost same time.(50 clients) I used socket option TCP_NODELAY. Thank you for great answer.

Comment: @bot TCP_NODELAY is best for low latency, however you might find it doesn't get the higher throughput results (as it avoid coalescing data) It is worth testing your throughput without this option.